# Is it possible to change locale in Symfony2 unit tests?

Tags: php, unit-testing, symfony, locale

I created a Locale Switcher for my project in symfony2 which consists in one route, and one method. The method get the locale given via GET, and if it fits the constraints, switch from the current locale to the one given. It works well.

My problem occurs when i want to write some unit tests concerning that Locale Switcher.

Even when my testing client get redirected (which means the locale switcher got called), the locale doesn't seems to change.

Firstly, is it possible to change the locale in unit tests ?
And Secondly, how can i get the current locale since i can't get the Request object in my testing method ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, i found the solution. I tried to access the Request object by creating one and hoping it'll be filled in the testing process. But, the request is stocked in the $client during unit tests.

So, to access the request object during units tests, simply do:

```
$client = static::createClient();
$client->getRequest()->getLocale();
```